# Creating a Review with React and Rails Backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

Im attempting to allow a user create a review for a game, using a custom star rating component.  The component itself is working, allowing users to click on the star value, but after they submit the review the stars come back empty...

Below is my ReviewForm, Review, ReviewsContainer(backend) and StarRating(custom star rating)..

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import StarRating from './StarRating'



class ReviewForm extends React.Component {
 
    state = {
        reviewed_game: '',
        rating: '',
        user_username: '',
    }
    
handleReviewedGame = (event) => {
    this.setState ({
        reviewed_game: event.target.value
     })
}


handleRating = (event) => {
    this.setState ({
        rating: event.target.value
     })
}

handleUser = (event) => {
    this.setState ({
        user_username: event.target.value
    })
}

handleForm = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    // console.log(e)
    const review = {
    reviewed_game: this.state.reviewed_game,
    rating: this.state.rating,
    }
    
   this.props.addReview(review)
    }
render() {
    return (
    <div className="form-container">
            <form onSubmit={(e) => {this.handleForm(e)}}>
                <div>
                    <label>Review</label>
                    <br></br>
                    <textarea type="text" placeholder="Drop Your Review" rows={10} cols={50} value={this.state.reviewed_game} onChange={this.handleReviewedGame}  className="form"/>
                    <div>
                    <label>Stars</label>
                    <br></br>
                    <StarRating  />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" className="sub-review">Create Review!</button>
            </form> 
        
    </div>
        )
    }
}
export default ReviewForm;
....
import React from 'react'
import StarRating from './StarRating'


class Review extends React.Component {

    state = {
        rating: ''
    }

    handleRating = (event) => {
        this.setState ({
            rating: event.target.value
         })
    }
    
render() {
    console.log(this.props)
    return (
<div className="review-container">
        <div className="review-card"> 
        <img src='../avatar.png' className="avatar" width="50" height="50" alt='avatar'/>
         <div className="review-username">{this.props.review.user_username}</div>
            <div className="review-content">Review: {this.props.review.reviewed_game}</div>
            <StarRating value={this.state.rating} />
            </div>
         </div>
        )
    }
}
....
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Review from './Review'
import ReviewForm from './ReviewForm'

export default class ReviewsContainer extends Component {

  state = {
    reviews: [],
}

componentDidMount(){
fetch('http://localhost:3000/reviews')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(reviews => this.setState({ reviews }))
}
            
  addReview = (review) => {
    console.log(review)
      fetch('http://localhost:3000/reviews',{
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
              "Content-Type" : "application/json",
              Accept: "application/json",
              Authorization: `bearer ${localStorage.token}`
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ review: review }
          ),
      })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(( json => {
          this.setState(prevState => ({
              reviews: [...prevState.reviews, json ]
             }))
      }))
  }

  handleShowForm = () => {
    this.setState({edit: false})

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="review-grid">
               <ReviewForm addReview={this.addReview} review={this.handleSubmit} />
        <h1 className="review-content">REVIEWS!</h1>
         <ul className="review-cards">
      {
        this.state.reviews.map(review => <Review key={review.id} review={review}/>)
      }  
    </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

...
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { FaStar} from 'react-icons/fa'

const StarRating = () => {
  const [rating, setRating] = useState(null);
  const [hover, setHover] = useState(null);
  return (
  <div>
    {[ ...Array(5)].map((star, i) => {
      const ratingValue = i + 1;
    return <label>
     <input type='radio'
      name='rating' 
      value={ratingValue}
      onClick={() => setRating(ratingValue)}
      />
      <FaStar className ='star' color={ratingValue <= (hover || rating) ? "yellow" : "grey"}size={25}
        onMouseEnter={() => setHover(ratingValue)}
        onMouseLeave={() => setHover(null)}
      />
    </label>
  })}
  </div>
  )
}

export default StarRating
```

Any advise appreciated! thank you!

Comment: Are you able to pass the user's rating into the star component? It looks like the state might be getting reset in the star component bc there's nothing going in there?

Comment: Something like this ... ```const [userRating, setUserRating]=useState(null);```

Comment: Ya and then if you're able to pass that into the star component and then if present show that otherwise show the blank